# Increase performance startup hybrid app

Tags: android, ios, performance, gwt, web-applications

I have a problem, when i startup my hybrid app. It takes very long to load the first page. ~40 seconds.

I work with **GWT**, **Google App Engine** and **RequestFactories**. I detected, that the app makes several request to the server (~ 10 requests).

Now i wonder, how can i increase the performance of staring up my app.

1. Group all request into one Request, which delivers all data with a single Request.
   (~300kb data)
2. Make a startup page, with low amount of requests and data.
   (~50kb data)
3. Better idea?

I prefer, that i can keep the current startup page. Can you share your experiance?

Comment: Did you profile your app? Since you are on the App Engine, you may face a cold startup time for new instances, which has nothing to do with your requests and data transfer.

Comment: Yes, that's not the problem. Anyway thanks for the advice.

Comment: You can see in your App Engine logs how long each request takes. Then you can see where the problem is right away. 40 seconds is way too much even for 10 requests and 300kB of data.

Comment: I agree, but the 40 seconds is only when I startup from iphone or from android. when i startup from browser it takes me ~ 10 sekonds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have pointed out the two main ways to reduce the start-up time.

1.- Reduce requests: With RF you can group all requests in one if you share the same service instance and call only once the .fire() method. Use Bundles for images, css, and other resources so as them are downloaded in the same request.

2.- Reduce the js size: split your code in pieces using GWT.runAsync(). So the first piece of code could be the minimum stuff for starting your app until the user interacts with it. You can use the gwt compilation reports to see whether your code is bigger. You can use the new closure compiler in gwt-2.5 to reduce and optimize the final js.

3.- Another thing you must check is that your webserver configuration is sending the appropriate headers so as the browser caches gwt fragments, as well as you should check if it is compressing the files before sending to the client. You can make gwt compiler to pre-compress those js fragments though.

4.- For successive loads, I mean the user goes to your app a second time, consider using localstorage for caching certain things which don't change instead of requesting them again. Configure your HTML5Manifest, if you are using mgwt, it is really easy since they include a linker to produce the manifest in compile time.

5.- Consider using light-weight widgets and frameworks instead of heavy widgets (js collections, elemental, gquery, mgwt, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I have several recommendation:

- Load data that changed rarely in a single request at start up.
- Activate GZip compression on your server.
- Use background call when application start up finished in user idle time.
- Group related request in a single request.